# sorting in elasticsearch by combination with threshold

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elastic search and would like to sort my collection based on a combination of relevance and id.

When I search by 'id', if I were to search my name, "john kealy", I would have tons of John's come up before me. If I search by relevance, I lose all ability to search my john kealy's by id. From my understanding, a combination sort would sort by a second parameter in the event of a tie, but I think that there's such a difference between a result "john kealy" and "john blabla", that i'd like the john kealy's to come first, sorted by id, then everything else sorted by id.

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

First recommendation for this: custom scoring lets you weight/adjust/emphasize/deemphasize/whatever to reflect the ranking you want/need.

EDIT:  Crikey, I'm getting old.  What you want is *function score*, not custom score.  Sorry about that.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-function-score-query.html